# Problem displaying a CSS 'popup' properly

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I'm having some trouble with displaying a popup div with CSS. The problem is better explained with an example. Take the following html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type"text/css">
            #popup {
                color: #fff;
                background: #8c0000
            }

            #form {
                background: #ccc;
                color: #000;
                position: absolute;
                display: none;
            }

            #popup:hover > #form {
                display: block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span id="popup">
            Popup 
            <div id="form">
                <form>
                    <label>Text Field</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                    <label>Select Field</label>
                    <select>
                        <option value="opt1">val1</option>
                        <option value="opt2">val2</option>
                    </select>
                </form>
            </div>
        </span>
    </body>
</html>
```

This consists of a single span element and a single hidden div element that contains a form. The div is displayed when the mouse is hovering the span element. The problem is that when I'm going to select an option in the dropdown box, the div disapears, as if it had lost focus. The result is that I can only change the dropdown value using the keyboard.

My question is: How do I fix that? Any clue on the subject is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you might be out of luck here, as rendering of `<option>` elements are dependent on browser / OS / platform, and not part of the CSS box model. Using JavaScript (and jQuery), this is pretty straight-forward. I've added a "Done" button to your form, as this might be a better solution for choosing when to hide the form. Otherwise, the user would have to be very careful not to move the mouse pointer outside the selection dropdown, or everything would disappear (if I've understood your request correctly.)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <style type"text/css">
            #popup {
                color: #fff;
                background: #8c0000
            }

            #form {
                background: #ccc;
                color: #000;
                position: absolute;
                display: none;
            }
        </style>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script language="javascript">
        function showForm() {
            $("#form").show();
        }
        function hideForm() {
            $("#form").hide();
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span id="popup" onmouseover="showForm()">
            Popup 
            <div id="form">
                <form>
                    <label>Text Field</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                    <label>Select Field</label>
                    <select>
                        <option value="opt1">val1</option>
                        <option value="opt2">val2</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="button" value="Done" onclick="hideForm()" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what, exactly, the problem is, but the following css works in Chrome 6.0.472.62 and Firefox 3.6.10 on Ubuntu 10.04:

```
#popup {
    position: relative;
}
#form {
    width: 12em;
    display: none;
}
#popup:hover #form {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1em;
    left: 0;
}
#popup form select:focus,
#popup form select:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Demo at: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/elike4/2/)

And it's worth changing `#popup` to a `div`, as (I thought I) commented earlier.

Comment: @Christian: there's two things to suggest: first, try my edited answer (originally I omitted to look at the 'when on select' part of your question, sorry), and second, what doctype are you using? Also: *invalid (x)html* will always cause problems. Your `#popup` **needs** to be a `div`, not a `span`.

Comment: that still doesn't work(trying on firefox 3.6.x). Originally I had tried using selectors to match elements inside the div, but they simply don't work. thanks anyway.

Comment: Ah, well. Looks like JS is definitely the way to go on this one, then.

Answer (score 0):

You are showing the popup only on hover, so when the mouse leaves your popup, it is hidden,

You have to show it onmouseover of the span element, and hide it when the use clicks somewhere else on the page (other than the *popup*) or probably when he hits the *close* option on the popup.

I dont think you can do that with pure CSS. You would need some javascript.

Comment: The `#form` is contained *within* the `#popup` span, so the `:hover` should still apply to the `#popup` regardless. It certainly does in Chrome 6.0.472.62 and Firefox 3.6.10.